# How does HTML differeciate between 2 <Mark> tags intersection

Tags: html

I have long text I want to display in HTML

There are 2 areas I have to highlight, one is red and the other is green

Here is an example

```
“Last night, Israeli forces <mark style="background: #ff0000">attacked the hospital with tanks and destroyed all of the first floor.</mark> The damage was very bad,” Murad said, <mark style="background: #00ff00">speaking to Al Jazeera from the Indonesian</mark> capital Jakarta.
```

This is ok and no issues if both areas do not intersect

something like this   **{Text Red}  [Text Green]**

But if the 2 areas intersect here comes the problem.

### Case 1

**{Text [Red  Text} Green]**

```
“Last night, Israeli forces <mark style="background: #ff0000">attacked the hospital with tanks and destroyed all <mark style="background: #00ff00">of the first floor.</mark> The damage was very bad,” Murad said, speaking to Al Jazeera from the Indonesian</mark> capital Jakarta.
```

### Case 2

**{Text [Text Green] Red}**

```
“Last night, Israeli forces <mark style="background: #ff0000">attacked the hospital with tanks and destroyed all <mark style="background: #00ff00">of the first floor.</mark> The damage was very bad,” Murad said, speaking to Al Jazeera from the Indonesian</mark> capital Jakarta.
```

as you can see the closing tag for both   and  is

how can I tell that the closeing tag  is for the Red or Green mark?

Answer (score 0):

The mark tag that you started is just going on that text but another mark recolors a piece at the end then the end  just ends it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. An element can only have one parent, so you can't have an element that spans across two elements.

The closest would be to create 3 elements, the red one, a child green one, and a sibling green one. But both green ones won't be the same element.

```css
.red {
  background: #ff0000;
  text-decoration: underline 2px solid blue;
}
.green {
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
“Last night, Israeli forces <mark class="red">attacked the hospital with tanks and destroyed all <mark class="green">of the first floor.</mark></mark><!-- Here we closed both previous <mark> and are opening the sibling one --><mark class="green"> The damage was very bad,” Murad said, speaking to Al Jazeera from the Indonesian</mark> capital Jakarta.
```

Note that even if you had different tag-names, the parser wouldn't allow such a tree:

```js
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<red-mark>some content<green-mark>green content</red-mark>more green content</green-mark>`, "text/html");
console.log("actual parsed markup", doc.body.innerHTML);
```

```css
green-mark { color: green }
red-mark { color: red }
```

```html
<red-mark>some red content<green-mark>green content</red-mark>more green content</green-mark>
```